# Can't share files publicly in google cloud storage using GUI

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Since last friday can't share newly uploaded files publicly. There is no checkbox to create public link at all.

This thread on google groups about the same problem:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/XDEvsuem8Hw

gsutil does work but that is not really convenient to use it every time.

Tried to clear cache, refresh/change browser, create/change/delete user,  manage permissions - nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed the same. My workaround in the UI is to do Edit Permissions

[image: GAE Cloud Storage Manager Edit Permissions]

and then add Read permission for the User "allUsers" (which I learned from a previously UI publicly shared file.)

[image]

You can verify that the sharing works by clicking on the public link and seeing that the file downloads now instead of giving a permission error.